# Syntax error when making psql Tables one-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, one-to-many, create-table

I`m trying to create some basic DB for my backend API.
I want a one-to many relation with order and order_products so there can be only one order(id) but there can be more rows in "order_products" with the same "order_id" but i get a syntax error:

syntax error at or near "order"
LINE 2:   "order_id" int REFERENCES order(id),
^
and i dont know why (This is in the order_products table).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "customers" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "first_name" varchar,
  "last_name" varchar,
  "username" varchar,
  "password" varchar,
  "email" varchar UNIQUE,
  "is_admin" boolean 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "address" (
  "customer_id" int REFERENCES customers(id),
  "zipcode" int,
  "country" varchar,
  "city" varchar,
  "street_name" varchar,
  "stree_number" varchar,
  "mobile_number" int
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "products" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "item_name" varchar UNIQUE,
  "description" text,
  "image_url" varchar,
  "price" float
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order" (
  "customer_id" int REFERENCES customers(id),
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "date_of_purchase" date,
  "total_price" int
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order_products" (
  "order_id" int REFERENCES order(id),
  "product_id" int REFERENCES products(id),
  "quantity" int,
  "total_price" int,
  UNIQUE(order_id, product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cart" (
  "customer_id" int REFERENCES customers(id),
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "date_of_purchase" date,
  "total_price" int
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cart_products" (
  "cart_id" int REFERENCES cart(id),
  "product_id" int REFERENCES products(id),
  "quantity" int,
  "total_price" int,
  UNIQUE(cart_id, product_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` is a reserved keyword, so you need to enclose it **always** in double quotes:

```
"order_id" int REFERENCES "order"(id),
```

In general I recommend to never use double quotes. For that you would need to find a different name for the `order` table that doesn't require quoting